# ember register inject singleton

Tags: ember.js, singleton

Trying to understand better about ember's register and inject.
Basically my code looks like this:

```
//creating a service
Nerdeez.Wormhole = Ember.Object.extend({
...
})

//registering this service as a singleton
App.register('wormhole:current', Nerdeez.Wormhole, {singleton: true});

//wanting to inject this service to be available everywhere in my application
//especially in the adapter where i use it in the ajax hook
App.inject('App', 'wormhole', 'wormhole:current');

//when trying to access this service in the ajax hook in the adapter i get undefined WTF!
App.get('wormhole') === undefined //true
```

i just want this service available globally in the entire application as a singleton, what is the best way to achieve this?
it's important to say that i manage to inject my service to models, views, and controllers and the problem is injecting it to my adapter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to inject the object into App either, but you can inject it into the adapter (or store) just like you can with for route & controller objects:

```
// register
App.register('wormhole:current', Nerdeez.Wormhole);

// inject into adapter
App.inject('adapter', 'wormhole', 'wormhole:current');

// inject into store
App.inject('store', 'wormhole', 'wormhole:current');

// inject into routes & controllers
App.inject('route', 'wormhole', 'wormhole:current');
App.inject('controller', 'wormhole', 'wormhole:current');
```