# How to inject dependency into store's adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use ember-data and I need to insert dependency into data adapter of store. Here is simplified code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    this.register('database:current', this.Database);

     // this works fine, this.get('database') inside routes works ok
    this.inject('route', 'database', 'database:current');

    // but this does not work
    this.inject(App.SqliteAdapter, 'database', 'database:current');

    // also tried this:
    // this.inject('dataAdapter', 'database', 'database:current');
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: App.SqliteAdapter
});

App.SqliteAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    var db = this.get('database');
    console.log(db); // this is undefined
  }
});

App.Database = Ember.Object.extend({});
```

Why doesn't this code work?

Versions:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.1.2
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.3
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject into your adapter like this:

```
this.inject('adapter', 'database', 'database:current');
```

You can see some more inject examples in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801209/161815) to [ember register inject singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17114408/161815).

Comment: Still does not work. Maybe because of newer versions of ember-data?

Comment: Well, you are using a fairly recent version of EmberData. Why are you specifying revision 13 in your store?

Comment: I copied that from somewhere. Do I even need to specify revisions?

Comment: @galymzhan no, you do not

Comment: @galymzhan not sure where you got that code, but you might want to start simpler. Ignore the specific ways I've extended the ActiveModel adapter & serializer in this example, but see you how can define what type of adapter to use simply by setting `App.ApplicationAdapter` (you don't need to pass `adapter` to the store). http://jsbin.com/UTAxIMU/3/

Comment: Does not work for me either. I've resolved to defining the property on the adapter and building computed properties from there.